Multiple regression with two continuous predictor variables with R
I'm trying to find a suitable multiple model (with two continuous predictor variables) for my data and I'm not sure if a linear model with lm() would be sufficient or whether I have to work with a non-linear solver like nls(). In terms of content, it's probably more of a general multiple modelling question than a specific R problem but since I want to do the modelling with R I'm hoping for help from the community on this problem.
I tried different linear model approaches. My predictor variables ("hl_log" and "kd_log") are both log10 transformed as they are equidistant on the log10 scale. I also tried a log transformation (log10 and square root) for my response variable ("recovery"), however I would prefer not to transform it.
Here is my test data (I have numerous data sets like that example data, each containing 110 data points):
test_data_reg <- structure(list(recovery = c(91.5513824667359, 91.5192979145041, 
91.3900160422761, 90.9729168632632, 80.7096348023025, 22.1411720298198, 
89.8150419930169, 67.6521657072756, 86.9944323865245, 45.6987826743418, 
86.0649240351043, 86.0875719543267, 86.0451071057847, 85.7554024723978, 
76.4537133150892, 21.435311880721, 84.776823629329, 64.4097386052656, 
82.2289327168066, 43.8803434934415, 74.8702462961216, 74.9853732188355, 
75.1099367745588, 75.0750212324243, 67.604038878928, 19.8395772388412, 
74.4342738510899, 57.5332641313579, 72.3940737944701, 39.8980843634991, 
55.380768141927, 55.5902613947344, 55.9073322638483, 56.1960932339341, 
51.5259035576106, 16.4952345003303, 56.0318958195716, 44.6277248277814, 
54.7598376899122, 31.9958478814759, 32.3865244880626, 32.5790318014532, 
32.9536661319241, 33.4481457016137, 31.5362838539209, 11.6740586958573, 
33.6774558837407, 28.0117014249316, 33.1518354251203, 21.1861847692743, 
12.9876380107578, 13.0357648391054, 13.2386524488063, 13.6557516278192, 
13.3603850146268, 6.05794092667736, 13.9945267528546, 12.209115787487, 
13.8860054732472, 9.87732377087855, 3.19788619420591, 3.15825233556667, 
3.15306218741153, 3.28734547513447, 3.38152307256771, 1.91374917429461, 
3.49900915353402, 3.17269038407096, 3.50816268755308, 2.72652637538926, 
0.506237614419175, 0.490619986788714, 0.465641219212985, 0.446900066056431, 
0.459809380013211, 0.309257336982165, 0.472114749457394, 0.437954137963575, 
0.487958856280079, 0.393016891573087, 0.0590770972916863, 0.0566820798339153, 
0.052941398509012, 0.046513164103048, 0.0305246767953194, 0.0220317070869114, 
0.0381088987449278, 0.0283995470416155, 0.034117202981976, 0.0261734453147117, 
0.00515004246484854, 0.00467962630933283, 0.00406558459941493, 
0.00341785410965368, 0.000899301689157309, 0.000603397187883363, 
0.0025867698405209, 0.000762130791733509, 0.00149919788619421, 
0.000692120411437199, 0.000316051712748891, 0.000270199112956497, 
0.000197518165518543, 0.000124752288383505, 1.50674719260168e-05, 
4.91931678777012e-06, 8.48994998584505e-05, 6.84835330753987e-06, 
5.36331037085968e-05, 5.66386713220723e-06), hl_log = c(3.33333333534272, 
3.33333333534272, 3.33333333534272, 3.33333333534272, 3.33333333534272, 
3.33333333534272, 3.33333333534272, 3.33333333534272, 3.33333333534272, 
3.33333333534272, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2.66666668223484, 
2.66666668223484, 2.66666668223484, 2.66666668223484, 2.66666668223484, 
2.66666668223484, 2.66666668223484, 2.66666668223484, 2.66666668223484, 
2.66666668223484, 2.33333339581721, 2.33333339581721, 2.33333339581721, 
2.33333339581721, 2.33333339581721, 2.33333339581721, 2.33333339581721, 
2.33333339581721, 2.33333339581721, 2.33333339581721, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.66666677580073, 1.66666677580073, 1.66666677580073, 
1.66666677580073, 1.66666677580073, 1.66666677580073, 1.66666677580073, 
1.66666677580073, 1.66666677580073, 1.66666677580073, 1.33333238790798, 
1.33333238790798, 1.33333238790798, 1.33333238790798, 1.33333238790798, 
1.33333238790798, 1.33333238790798, 1.33333238790798, 1.33333238790798, 
1.33333238790798, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.666667711458589, 
0.666667711458589, 0.666667711458589, 0.666667711458589, 0.666667711458589, 
0.666667711458589, 0.666667711458589, 0.666667711458589, 0.666667711458589, 
0.666667711458589, 0.333326340403454, 0.333326340403454, 0.333326340403454, 
0.333326340403454, 0.333326340403454, 0.333326340403454, 0.333326340403454, 
0.333326340403454, 0.333326340403454, 0.333326340403454, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), kd_log = c(-1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073, -1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073, -1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073, -1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073, -1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073, -1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073, -1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073, -1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073, -1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073, -1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073, -1, -0.666754301038037, -0.333294863880101, 
0, 1, 2, 0.333326340403454, 1.33333238790798, 0.666667711458589, 
1.66666677580073)), row.names = c(NA, -110L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

My linear model approach which gained the best fit (R² of 0.9608) for this data set was:
model1 <- lm(formula = recovery ~  0 + kd_log + I(kd_log^2) + I(hl_log^2) + kd_log:hl_log,
                 data = test_data_reg)

However, the residuals of this model ranged between -31 and 18 % which is no good at all. Since the response varaible "recovery" is in percentage it should be within the range of 0 - 100, thus the predicted values of the model should be limited accordingly. To my knowlegde setting boundaries on the coefficients or the predicted values is not possible using the linear model function lm()?
Accordingly I think a non-linear model might by more appropriate in this case as it has the possibility to set parameter boundaries (e.g. in nls_multstart()), apart from the possibility that the data can only be described by a non-linear model anyway. I guess I have to find appropriate functions describing the correlation between each predictor and the response separately and possibly also a term for the interaction of both predictor variables?
I would be very grateful for any help or suggestions on how to find a suitable modelling approach for such data!

You seem to be confusing the residuals and the predicted values. Residuals in a linear model will always be both positive and negative and that is not, in itself, a problem, even if they DV has to be positive.

However, even once that gets straightened out, you may want to consider beta regression on the proportion.

@Mogens Did you drop the intercept from your equation on purpose? This gives a higher R square than with the intercept included.

Since you have percentage values but not exactly 0 or 100 %, beta-regression might be appropriate.
test_data_reg$recovery <- test_data_reg$recovery / 100

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(test_data_reg, aes(x = kd_log, y = recovery, color = hl_log)) +
  geom_point()
print(p1)

p2 <- ggplot(test_data_reg, aes(x = hl_log, y = recovery, color = kd_log)) +
  geom_point()
print(p2)

range(test_data_reg$recovery)
#no exact zero or 1 --> beta-regression could be appropriate

library(betareg)
fit1 <- betareg(recovery ~ kd_log * hl_log, data = test_data_reg)
summary(fit1)

pred_data <- expand.grid(hl_log = (0:10) / 3,
                         kd_log = (-3:6) / 3)
pred_data$recovery <- predict(fit1, newdata = pred_data, type = "response")                         

p1 + geom_line(data = pred_data, aes(group = factor(hl_log)))
p2 + geom_line(data = pred_data, aes(group = factor(kd_log)))

This doesn't fit well. You could now try to find some more complex parametric linear or even non-linear relationship (e.g., https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0254103) but that should be derived from domain knowledge. I would suggest fitting a generalized additive model (GAM, https://doi.org/10.1201/9781315370279) with beta-regression family. I could create an almost perfect fit with that approach.
library(mgcv)
#we use two 1-D smooth and a 2-D interaction smooth to assess the interaction separately
#we could combine everything in a tensor smooth: recovery ~ te(kd_log, hl_log)
fit2 <- gam(recovery ~ s(kd_log) +  s(hl_log) + ti(kd_log, hl_log), data = test_data_reg, family = betar)

summary(fit2)
# Family: Beta regression(30113.674) 
# Link function: logit 
# 
# Formula:
# recovery ~ s(kd_log) + s(hl_log) + ti(kd_log, hl_log)
# 
# Parametric coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -3.51857    0.03459  -101.7   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#                      edf Ref.df   Chi.sq p-value    
# s(kd_log)          8.482  8.804    510.7  <2e-16 ***
# s(hl_log)          8.326  8.695 462156.8  <2e-16 ***
# ti(kd_log,hl_log) 13.342 14.286  29142.6  <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# R-sq.(adj) =      1   Deviance explained =  100%
# -REML = -604.14  Scale est. = 1         n = 110

#plots on scale of linear predictor
plot(fit2, pages = 1, scheme = 2)


pred_data <- expand.grid(hl_log = (0:10) / 3,
                         kd_log = (-3:6) / 3)
pred_data$recovery <- predict(fit2, newdata = pred_data, type = "response")                         

p1 + geom_line(data = pred_data, aes(group = factor(hl_log)))


p2 + geom_line(data = pred_data, aes(group = factor(kd_log)))



thanks a lot @Roland for your Input on this topic. I think your approach is very sufficient delivering great model predictions. So far I only used lm() or nls() and was not aware of generalized additive models, which seems to be a good approach for this case...

GAM seems to be a tempting approach in this case, but I just realized after a short research, that it wont work for me. Reason is that Im overall interested in the model predictions of the response. In the end I want to export the equations for the response with its parameters/coeficcients into an excel tool, so that people with no R and modelling knowlegde can quickly predict the recovery using kd/kd_log (the linear sorption coefficient which is my predictor no. 1) and hl/hl_log (the half live, which is my predictor no. 2). Im very greatful for any further suggestions or idears on this topic!

Then you need to derive a parametric model from scientific theory. There should be models in the literature if your data results from sorption/degradation experiments.
